# how to export function and import it as a module in lwc? it makes a return value error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm new in lwc.
I was supposed to export function and import it as a module in lwc,
but when i deploy the JS file which has export function it shows i didn't return a value.

I really don't know which value i should return.
Could you please help me?

Here is my utils.js

```
export function exportCSVFile(headers, totalData, fileTitle){
    
    if(!totalData || !totalData.length) {
        return null
    }
    const jsonObject = JSON.stringify(totalData)
    const result = convertToCSV(jsonObject, headers)
    if(!result){
        return null
    }
    const blob = new Blob([result])
    const exportedFileName = fileTitle? fileTitle+ '.csv': 'export.csv'
    if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFileName)

    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)){
        const link = window.document.createElement('a')
        link.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(result);
        link.target = "_blank"
        link.download = exportedFileName
        link.click()
    } else {
        const link = window.document.createElement('a')
        if(link.download !== undefined){
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            link.setAttribute("href", url)
            link.setAttribute("download", exportedFileName)
            link.style.visibility="hidden"
            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
            document.body.removeChild(link)
        }      
    }
  
} 

function convertToCSV(objArray, headers){
...
 return str
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an eslint error, which should not necessarily prevent deployment. Regardless, eslint would complain because you're sometimes returning a value (`return null` is still returning a value), versus the last line of your function, which does not return a value. Realistically, you should be able to fix this by changing `return null` to just `return`.